# Google Charts Timeline - Move Date/Year to the Top of the Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Here is a sample of a Google Superbowl Timeline:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation

Is there a way to move the Date/Year to the top of the Timeline Chart?

Alternatively, are there any other Timeline Charts that would provide additional customization?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't find any Google option, but I did this with SVG transformation

https://jsfiddle.net/d1x5hyes/1/

```
function afterDraw() {
    var g = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].getElementsByTagName("g")[1];
    document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].parentNode.style.top = '40px';
    document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
    var height = Number(g.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].getAttribute('y')) + 15;
    g.setAttribute('transform','translate(0,-'+height+')');
    g = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will remove the years completely, correct?

Comment: @Shogg I tried this code on my chart but I got an error Cannot read getAttribute of undefined.Do you have any idea what can caused this?

Comment: This worked on my gantt chart aswell, but it removed all the styling on it from the options.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @shoggs answer, here is how to move the labels to the top on a Google Gantt chart, while preserving the formatting of the rows.

```
let labels = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].getElementsByTagName("g")[1].getElementsByTagName("text")
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.overflow = 'visible'
for (var i=0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].setAttribute("y", -15)                                                                                                
}
```